# How set specific range for randomly deployment ports on Dokku

Tags: docker, deployment, range, port, dokku

I builded a self hosted dokku server that will deploy the application by using an ip and setting a random port for applications. This server is running on a vm, that im using the port forward to access the guest services. I want to set a specific range of ports (for example 8000 - 8100) that will randomly used by dokku deployment, cause i will allow this ports on my firewall, so it need to be a restricted range of ports.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Show what you tried, and where exactly you got stuck

Comment: I have configured the dokku to run without host naming, so it will generate a random port when i deploy the application (like my-app:2188). This port is randomly generated. i just want to know if is possible to set a constraint for randomly port generate, like 8000 - 8100 - so it can generate my-app:8082 but not my-app:2043

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to restrict the autogenerated port range at this time. At this time, you can set the port afterwards by running the following:

```sh
# where APP is your app name 
dokku config:set APP DOKKU_PROXY_PORT=8080 DOKKU_PROXY_SSL_PORT=8443
```